# Save image to NV memory of Epson PosPrinter using ESC/POS commands in c#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, thermal-printer, epson, escpos

I am currently working on a project that involves printing to an EPSON Thermal printer from within Xamarin.Forms targetting Android.
I have bound the Epson Android SDK into a Java binding for forms and can print to the printer using that.

However there is a need to store logos into the NV memory of the printer, for printing later. It has been decided that the application is to do this periodically instead of using the Epson utility to remotely connect to each printer and do so. This is to ensure that the graphics are kept upto date throughout our estate.

> I have found the following command from Epson which acheives what I require: https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=70
>   however I am confused around the parameters.

Particularly the parameters xL, xH and yL and yH.

Does anyone have any idea how using c# I can create a method that takes a bitmap and converts it ready for use with this command?

Thank you.

Comment: Hey Mark I'm trying to print to a Epson printer but when creating a Java bindings from the jar I'm not able to use all the features of the jar due to interfaces used. I'm using ePOS2.jar. Can you tell me how were you able to print with your java binding?

Comment: Hey @AbsoluteSith, I I just bound the ePOS2.jar file into a standard java binding project. I then had to customise the Metadata.xml file to hide specific unused methods and also add in he libepos2.so files into the libs folder. If you need any more help let me know. I will put the metadata.xml into the next comment

Comment: Metadata: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjvvktNAGqghg-V4dKEIbdSAFlRD_Q

Comment: Hey Mark thanks for the help greatly appreciated. If possible could you send me a sample code so it would be better I'm running into a few dependencies issue.

Comment: Hi Mark, were you able to do this in Xamarin.Android? I am also trying to do something similar but cannot bind the native library epos2.so correctly. Can you please help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @jonDoe I didn't ever resolve this issue no but I did manage to bind the native library into a Xamarin bindings project...what issues are you having?

Comment: @MarkLowe I am getting this:
 
/Users/biswas/Documents/Hybrid/Xamarin/EpsonEPOSSDKBinding/EpsonEPOSSDKBinding/obj/Debug/generated/src/Com.Epson.Epos2.Printer.Printer.cs(60,60): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'LogoKeyCode' does not exist in the namespace 'Com.Epson.Epos2.Printer' (are you missing an assembly reference?) (CS0234) (EpsonEPOSSDKBinding)

Comment: if you have the binding project or anything, can you please help me with that?

Comment: @jonDoe.. I don't think I have the project anymore as it was from when I was working for a previous project. All I did was bind the jar file as normal and set my metadata.xml file to be this: https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AHShCG3UgBZUQ_0&cid=21A81A40D392EF3B&id=21A81A40D392EF3B%2162200&parId=root&o=OneUp and then it built. I'll see if I can find the project. What version of the Epson SDK are you using?